# Which countries have the least travel restrictions for vaccinated people?

Tags: usa, international-travel, covid-19

There are certain countries that are loosening their restrictions around travel, I am curious which countries are the easiest to travel for Americans right now?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Now is a great time to travel if you’re vaccinated! The linked question should help answer your question.

Comment: But be careful as many countries still have high numbers of cases and even double vaccinated people can get COVID 19 and get pretty poorly from it. Keep safe.